# Rails: how to not render view by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm integrating AngularJS with Rails, and am trying to figuring out if I should go with yield, ui-view, or both. At the moment I'm having ui-view with angular-rails-templates, but without `<%= yield %>` in application.html.erb Rails is still requesting default views (e.g. views/users/edit.html.erb).

I saw in Rails' documentation that,

> The rule is that if you do not explicitly render something at the end of a controller action, Rails will automatically look for the action_name.html.erb template in the controller's view path and render it.

So, how do I stop rails from requesting the basically empty view files? Or should I have structured this differently?

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want to do is have the application.html.erb layout, but no template so your angular can do all the work.

This is not the best architectural design and probably breaks some best practices, but what you can do is this. Create a copy of application.html.erb and call it something.html.erb where "something" is your action. So by default it will request this template. Then do:

```
render :layout => false
```

or

```
layout false
```

Basically what we are doing is moving the layout code to a template level and disable layouts so we only request for one view file.